# How to assign a private endpoint to a web.app slot using bicep script

Tags: azure-bicep

I have a application defined as and I am trying to figure out how to map the preview slot to

```
resource app 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: '${appName}-${env}'
  location: location

  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }

  properties: {
    serverFarmId: servicePlanId
    httpsOnly: true
    // clientAffinityEnabled: false
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: subnetId

    siteConfig: {
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have defined a slot

```
resource stagingSlot 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'preview'
  parent: app
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: servicePlanId
  }
}
```

Now I need to create a private endpoint for the main site and for the slot.

the slot gets created and the endpoint connection also but only to the parent item not the release slot

```
resource stagingSlotEndpoint 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/privateEndpointConnections@2022-03-01' = {
  name: '${appName}-preview'
  kind: 'app'
  parent: stagingSlot
  properties: {
    privateLinkServiceConnectionState: {
      status: 'Approved'
      description: 'Auto-Approved'
      actionsRequired: 'None'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign a private endpoint connection to a web app slot, you need to use [`Microsoft.Web/sites/privateEndpointConnections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/privateendpointconnections?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) resource type.

*Add below code to yours and it will work as expected.*

```bash
resource prodSiteEndpoint 'Microsoft.Web/sites/privateEndpointConnections@2022-03-01' = {
   name: 'app-produ'
   kind: 'app'
   parent: app
   properties: {
     privateLinkServiceConnectionState: {
     status: 'Approved'
     description: 'Auto-Approved'
     actionsRequired: 'None'
   }
}
 dependsOn: [
   appConfigurationPrivateEndPoint
   appConfigurationPrivateDnsZoneGroup
  ]
}
```

[image]

*complete bicep code:*

```bash
param location string = 'eastus'
param appConfigurationPrivateEp string = 'priend'
param appdns string = 'priend-nic'
resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-12-01' existing = {
  name: 'uovh4pk4fceb6kic6v5wmtms62'
}
resource app 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: 'uovh4pk4fceb6'
}

resource appConfigurationPrivateEndPoint 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints@2021-03-01' existing= {
  name: appConfigurationPrivateEp
}
resource appConfigurationPrivateDnsZoneGroup 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups@2021-03-01' existing= {
  parent: appConfigurationPrivateEp
  name: appdns
}

resource stagingSlot 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'stagingpreviewbla'
  parent: app
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
  }
}
resource stagingSlotEndpoint 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/privateEndpointConnections@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'app-preview'
  kind: 'app'
  parent: stagingSlot
  properties: {
    privateLinkServiceConnectionState: {
      status: 'Approved'
      description: 'Auto-Approved'
      actionsRequired: 'None'
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    appConfigurationPrivateEndPoint
    appConfigurationPrivateDnsZoneGroup
  ]
}
resource prodSiteEndpoint 'Microsoft.Web/sites/privateEndpointConnections@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'app-produ'
  kind: 'app'
  parent: app
  properties: {
    privateLinkServiceConnectionState: {
      status: 'Approved'
      description: 'Auto-Approved'
      actionsRequired: 'None'
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    appConfigurationPrivateEndPoint
    appConfigurationPrivateDnsZoneGroup
  ]
}
```